# NSDate crashing on simulators less than 5s on versions iOS 8.4 and 9.3

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

I'm having a strange bug where my application will crash on all simulators less than the iPhone 5s.

Firstly, I've tried resetting all the simulators and the crash still persists.

#### Code

```
extension NSDate {

  func firstDayOfMonth() -> NSDate {
    let cal = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let comp = cal.components([.Year, .Month], fromDate: self)

    // to 12pm
    comp.hour = 12
    comp.minute = 0
    comp.second = 0

    return cal.dateFromComponents(comp)!
  }


  func lastDayOfMonth() -> NSDate {
    let cal = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let comp = NSDateComponents()

    comp.month = 1
    comp.day -= 1

    // to 12pm
    comp.hour = 12
    comp.minute = 0
    comp.second = 0

    return cal.dateByAddingComponents(comp, toDate: self.firstDayOfMonth()!, options: [])!
  }
}
```

#### The Error

The final line of code in the second function:
`cal.dateByAddingComponents(comp, toDate: self.firstDayOfMonth()!, options: [])!`
returns `5828963-12-20 00:00:00 +0000` on the devices where the crash occurs.

#### Reproducing the Error

I'm able to consistently reproduce the issue when running on the iPhone 4s (v8.4, v9.3) and iPhone 5 (v8.4, v9.3) however the error does not occur in the playground or on the iPhone 5s or iPhone 6/6s

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this alternative date math

```
extension NSDate {

  func firstDayOfMonth() -> NSDate {

    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    var startDate : NSDate?
    calendar.rangeOfUnit(.Month, startDate: &startDate, interval: nil, forDate: self)
    let components = calendar.components([.Year, .Month, .Day], fromDate: startDate!)
    components.hour = 12
    return calendar.dateFromComponents(components)!
  }

  func lastDayOfMonth() -> NSDate {

    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let dayRange = calendar.rangeOfUnit(.Day, inUnit: .Month, forDate: self)
    let dayLength = dayRange.length
    let components = calendar.components([.Year, .Month, .Day], fromDate: self)
    components.day = dayLength
    components.hour = 12
    return calendar.dateFromComponents(components)!
  }
}
```

**Swift 3**

```
extension Date {

    func firstDateOfMonth() -> Date {

        let calendar = Calendar.current
        var startDate = Date()
        var interval : TimeInterval = 0
        _ = calendar.dateInterval(of:.month, start: &startDate, interval: &interval, for: self)
        return startDate
    }

    func lastDateOfMonth() -> Date {

        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let dayRange = calendar.range(of:.day, in: .month, for: self)!
        let dayLength = dayRange.upperBound
        var components = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: self)
        components.day = dayLength
        return calendar.date(from:components)!
    }
}
```

Setting the hour to 12 can be useful especially in Brasil where one of the daylight saving dates skips 0:00 to 0:59.

Answer (score 1):

This could be happening because of an Integer overflow. `iPhone 5s` and above use `64-bit` processors where as below ones use `32-bit`. Do check this apple documentation regarding finding out diffrence between days using `dateFromComponents`..

From [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtCalendricalCalculations.html)...

> Do not use this method for comparing second differences because it overflows NSInteger on 32-bit platforms.

**Possible solution to avoid the crash**

- Try removing the seconds from your date comparison.

Comment: I've removed the seconds and no luck i'm afraid. I'll check the link though thanks!